# write a txt file in a format starting vector?

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files

I want to do the opposite of what has been explained in this question:

> [problems with data acquisition from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595485/other-problems-with-data-acquisition-from-matlab)

I would pass by the vectors (eg. `codeserv = [NNNNNNNNNN ....]
area = [IIIIIII ....] [.........]`) to create the text file with the same format as in the link, ie:

```
* Comment line
| Code | serv | etc. ...
* Comment line
Figures | Figures | Figures | etc. ......
```

We must rebuild a new drive or you can adapt the code?

Thanks for your help and information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little sample, what should help you to save your first file out of Matlab onto your hard drive.

```
%some nr to integrate into the printf
num=2.0 
%opens the file: 'file_name' with write access 
f = fopen(file_name,'w');
%writes some text into the file
fprintf(f,'test-file dump\r\n');
%writes text and includes a fload number out of matlab workspace
fprintf(f,'some-float=%f \r\n', num);
%important closes the file, other wise no other program can grand write access on the file
fclose(f);
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: See also, `dlmwrite`, using a `|` delimiter.

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm trying to implmentare your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *textscan* in order to scan some input, you may use *fprintf* for output.