# Reading text data from a CSV file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv, data-import

my data is in following form:

```
days of week      date        time(hrs)        visitors
mon            jan 2 2010     900               501 
mon            jan 2 2010    1000               449
mon            jan 2 2010    1100               612
```

likewise for every day for entire year.
i need to create a matrix of days of week as shown below:

```
A=[
    mon
    mon
    mon
]
```

Comment: BTW jan-2-2010 was a Saturday :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would read the *tab-separated values*, and parse the dates:

```
%# read and parse file
fid = fopen('data.csv','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %s %d', 'Delimiter','\t', 'HeaderLines',1, ...
    'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true, 'CollectOutput',false);
fclose(fid);

%# get date and number of visitors
dt = datenum(strcat(C{2}, {' '}, C{3}), 'mmm dd yyyy HHMM');
visitors = C{4};

%# plot
plot(dt,visitors)
datetick('x')
xlabel('time of day'), ylabel('visitors')
```

[image]

As for the day-of-week column, you can get it as:

```
>> C{1}                        %# first column from file
ans = 
    'mon'
    'mon'
    'mon'

>> cellstr(datestr(dt,'ddd'))  %# actual day of week from parsed dates
ans = 
    'Sat'
    'Sat'
    'Sat'
```

this produces different days (either your data posted was simply made-up, or you have a bug in the part that generated those dates!)

Comment: So far as I can tell, this still fails if my strings contain `\n`  .  This can occur when exporting from Excel to `csv` and come cells contain internal line breaks.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's tricky, new lines in the field values themselves.. are the fields quoted? maybe look into the `%q` specifier instead of `%s`?

Comment: btw do you mean the literal string `\n` or an actual new line (i.e LF/CRLF)?

Comment: the newline character.  You can see this if you write some multiline text in Excel using the <ALT>-<ENTER> method of line breaks, then export to CSV and open in some decent text editor.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft alright I just tried it, and the `%q` specifier works. Here is my example: http://pastebin.com/Nwd8Vcwx. The trick is that if there is a newline in a field, it must be quoted (which is what Excel does by default).

Comment: Good to know.  I'll go back and see why my use of `%q` was fouling up.

Answer (score 0):

Taking prompts from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584003/),

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt');
% Skip a line for the header
s = fgetl(fid);
% Read the rest into data
data = textscan(fid, '%s %s %d %d %d %d');
% Close the file
fclose(fid);
```

The days of the week are in the first cell of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

You could download my [csvimport](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport) submission from the File Exchange. Assuming your data is tab separated, you can read it using:

```
[days datecol timecol visitors] = csvimport( 'file.txt', 'delimiter', '\t', ...
       'columns', {'days of week', 'date', 'time(hrs)', 'visitors'} );
```

The first 2 output parameters will cell arrays of strings while the last 2 will be double matrices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting started with (a recent version of) matlab, the easiest way is to use the 'import wizard'.

A few simple steps:

1. Browse to your file and right click it
2. Choose the option to import
3. Select the choice to store things as `cell array` (Vectors or matrices wont work).
4. Click Import

Optionally you can click next to import and select that you want to generate the code for this procedure. However, this will likely be a bit verbose. If you just need to do it once, I would recommend this method.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use `dlmread`. It can take any ASCII delimiter. I think it might suit your requirements. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html).