# Convert csv file to mat file

Tags: matlab, csv, mat

I have a csv file as follows:

```
StringA,StringB ...
1.234,13.45 ...
```

I want to convert this into a `.mat` file extension but when I try to read the csv file, it throws and error due to the fact that I have strings in the first row. This makes it difficult to directly convert to a mat file as I also want the headers in my mat file. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759657/reading-text-data-from-a-csv-file-in-matlab

Comment: I actually want the headers in the mat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your file format, you can use `importdata()` like this:

```
M = importdata('myfile.txt', ',', 1);
```

The header will be saved in `M.colheaders`, the data will be stored in `M.data`.

Please have a look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) for further information and a working example.