# Importing many csv files

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I have a folder full of 'N' number of .csv files with size (m , n). I want to import them and at the same time convert each file into a column matrix of size (mxn) and store them in a (mxn , N) size matrix with each column having the name of the corresponding file.

My code is not able to retrieve the data out of the .csv files and is showing an error. The data is a monthly mean rainfall data with thirteen columns (year, jan, feb......dec) and I do not want to import the year column as it does not have the rainfall value rather just year value.

My code is

```
list=dir('*.csv');
N=numel(list);
h=zeros(1300,N);
for k =1:1:N;
    data=csvread(list(k).name);
    M=size(data);
    for j=1:M(1)
        for i=1:M(1)
            h(i+1+(j-1)*12,k)=data(j,i);
        end
    end
end
```

Here `h` is the matrix in which I want to store all the data.

```
Error using dlmread (line 138)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 1u) ==> "Year"  "Jan" "Feb"
"Mar"   "Apr"   "May"   "Jun"   "Jul"   "Aug"   "Sep"   "Oct"   "Nov"   "Dec"\n
```

Though the above code is in matlab any reply in R programming language will also be acceptable.

Comment: Workflow in R has been described many times. Please do a search along the lines of "importing many files". To narrow it down, you'll need functions `list.files()`, `do.call()` and of course `read.table()` or any of its variants.

Comment: `csvread` is for numeric data only. You have to use another function to read in, for example this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759657/reading-text-data-from-a-csv-file-in-matlab

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import CSV file with mixed data types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [csvread](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) documentation, it states that the file must contain only numeric values. Since your file contains other datatypes like strings, you could use [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) (see the documentation for more details).

Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747834/import-csv-file-with-mixed-data-types) in stackoverflow. A custom function using textscan and [fgetl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fgetl.html) have been used to read csv files with mixed data type. The below code is taken from the thread mentioned above. The code has been provided in the answer written by [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4801735/3449335).

```
function lineArray = read_mixed_csv(fileName,delimiter)
  fid = fopen(fileName,'r');   %# Open the file
  lineArray = cell(100,1);     %# Preallocate a cell array (ideally slightly
                               %#   larger than is needed)
  lineIndex = 1;               %# Index of cell to place the next line in
  nextLine = fgetl(fid);       %# Read the first line from the file
  while ~isequal(nextLine,-1)         %# Loop while not at the end of the file
    lineArray{lineIndex} = nextLine;  %# Add the line to the cell array
    lineIndex = lineIndex+1;          %# Increment the line index
    nextLine = fgetl(fid);            %# Read the next line from the file
  end
  fclose(fid);                 %# Close the file
  lineArray = lineArray(1:lineIndex-1);  %# Remove empty cells, if needed
  for iLine = 1:lineIndex-1              %# Loop over lines
    lineData = textscan(lineArray{iLine},'%s',...  %# Read strings
                        'Delimiter',delimiter);
    lineData = lineData{1};              %# Remove cell encapsulation
    if strcmp(lineArray{iLine}(end),delimiter)  %# Account for when the line
      lineData{end+1} = '';                     %#   ends with a delimiter
    end
    lineArray(iLine,1:numel(lineData)) = lineData;  %# Overwrite line data
  end
end
```

Running the function is as simple as

```
data_csv = read_mixed_csv('filename.csv', ',');
```

The function can be easily modified to suit your needs. Hope it helps