# Need a method to store a lot of data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, large-data

I've asked this before, but I feel I wasn't clear enough so I'll try again.

I am running a network simulation, and I have several hundreds output files. Each file holds the simulation's test result for different parameters.

There are 5 different parameters and 16 different tests for each simulation. I need a method to store all this information (and again, there's a lot of it) in Matlab with the purpose of plotting graphs using a script. suppose the script input is parameter_1 and test_2, so I get a graph where parameter_1 is the X axis and test_2 is the Y axis.

My problem is that I'm not quite familier to Matlab, and I need to be directed so it doesn't take me forever (I'm short on time).

How do I store this information in Matlab? I was thinking of two options:

1. Each output file is imported separately to a different variable (matrix)
2. All output files are merged to one output file and imprted together. In the resulted matrix each line is a different output file, and each column is a different test. Problem is, I don't know how to store the simulation parameters
   Edit: maybe I can use a dataset?

So, I would appreciate any suggestion of how to store the information, and what functions might help me fetch the only the data I need.

Comment: For someone who is *not quite familier to Matlab* this strikes me as a ridiculously ambitious first project.  What software packages are you familiar with ?  Why do you think you need to use Matlab for this ?

Comment: Wasn't Matlab created for this reason? Storing and filtering the data in excel (I'm using python) is easy, but there's no easy way of plotting a graph in python. Maybe I could store and fetch the information in Excel and then use Matlab just for the plot?

Comment: Maybe you could store and fetch the information in Excel and then use Excel for the plotting too ?  I'm not suggesting that Matlab is not suitable for what you wish to do, but that your Matlab skills are not (yet) suitable and that since you are short of time struggling with Matlab will not help you to finish your project quickly and without stress.

Comment: For now I'll try to stay with Matlab, and see how it goes. What about implementing method 2 on my list using a dataset? Thanks anyway!

Comment: "there's no easy way of plotting a graph in python" - [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking to give matlab a try with this problem, you can iterate through all the files and import them one by one. You can create a list of the contents of a folder with the function

```
ls(name)
```

and you can import data like this:

```
A = importdata(filename)
```

if your data is in txt files, you should consider this [Prev Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584003/acquire-data-from-text-files-in-matlab?rq=1)

A good strategy to avoid cluttering your workspace is to import them all into a single matrix. SO if you have a matrix called VAR, then VAR{1,1}.{1,1} could be where you put your test results and VAR{1,1}.{2,1} could be where you put your simulation parameters of the first file. I think that is simpler than making a data structure. Just make sure you uniformly place the information in the same indexes of the arrays. You could also organize your VAR row v col by parameter vs test.

This is more along the lines of your first suggestion

> Each output file is imported separately to a different variable
>   (matrix)

Your second suggestion seems unnecessary since you can just iterate through your files.

Comment: Ok, say I have VAR like you suggested. Now I want to plot a graph of parameter_1 and test_1, but the other parameters also has to hold specific values that I define. What function should I use/read about?
Thanks!

Comment: And another idea: if I use a map where the key is the parameters, can I look for keys with regex?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, couldn't you just reference the data in VAR when you plot? I should think you can systematically iterate through your VAR for the given test results and parameters, and save your figures. If you can elaborate I will try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `save` to store your data.
It is very convenient, and can store as much data as your hard disk can bear.

The documentation is there:
http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/save.html

Comment: Saving the data wasn't really the problem, but rather how to store the data in Matlab

Answer (score 0):

Describe the format of text files. Because if it has a systematic format then you can use `dlmread` or similar commands in matlab and read the text file in a matrix. From there, you can plot easily. If you try to do it in excel, it will be much slower than reading from a text file. If speed is an issue for you, I suggest that you don't go for Excel.